# How to order months between two years in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have the following table in SQL:

```
UniqueUsers YEAR     MONTH     MONTH2
NULL        NULL     January     1
NULL        NULL     February    2
NULL        NULL     July        7
NULL        NULL     August      8
NULL        NULL     September   9
NULL        NULL     October     10
NULL        NULL     November    11
NULL        NULL     December    12
1           2016     March       3
2           2016     April       4
2           2016     May         5
1           2016     June        6
```

In SSRS I have a table grouped by Month with 4 parameters: 1 for Year1 and 1 for Month1; 1 for Year2 and 1 for Month2.

For example, if I select Year1 = 2015 and Month1 = November and December and Year2 = 2016 and Month2 = January and February I need to show the months like this even if the results have NULL values:

```
Nov Dec Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct
```

This is the query than I use:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT
      [QUARTER]
      ,[CARRIER]
      ,[PLANGROUP]
      ,[UniqueUsers]
      ,[YEAR]
      ,A.[MONTH]
      ,A.[MONTH2]
FROM [ReportUnit].[dbo].[Month_List] A

LEFT JOIN

(SELECT
        [YEAR]
        ,[MONTH2]
        ,[CARRIER]
        ,[PLANGROUP]
        ,[QUARTER]
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT [CONTRACT_NUM]) AS [UniqueUsers]
FROM
(
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT
        MIN([YEAR]) AS [YEAR]
        ,MIN([MONTH2]) AS [MONTH2]
        ,DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, MIN([MONTH2])-1, CAST('2017-01-01' AS datetime))) AS [MONTH]
        ,[CARRIER]
        ,[PLANGROUP]
        ,MIN([QUARTER]) AS [QUARTER]
        ,[CONTRACT_NUM]
FROM MyTable
WHERE
[YEAR] = @YEAR1
AND [PLANGROUP] IN (@ACCOUNT)
GROUP BY [PLANGROUP],[CARRIER],[CONTRACT_NUM]
) Q1
WHERE
[MONTH] IN (@MONTH1) --THIS IS MONTH NAME PARAMETER IN SSRS
--[MONTH2] IN (11,12)

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT
        MIN([YEAR]) AS [YEAR]
        ,MIN([MONTH2]) AS [MONTH2]
        ,DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, MIN([MONTH2])-1, CAST('2017-01-01' AS datetime))) AS [MONTH]
        ,[CARRIER]
        ,[PLANGROUP]
        ,MIN([QUARTER]) AS [QUARTER]
        ,[CONTRACT_NUM]
FROM MyTable
WHERE
[YEAR] = @YEAR2
AND [PLANGROUP] IN (@ACCOUNT)
GROUP BY [PLANGROUP],[CARRIER],[CONTRACT_NUM]
) Q1
WHERE
[MONTH] IN (@MONTH2)  --THIS IS MONTH NAME PARAMETER IN SSRS
--[MONTH2] IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
) Q1
GROUP BY [YEAR],[MONTH2],[PLANGROUP],[CARRIER],[QUARTER]
) B ON A.MONTH2 = B.MONTH2
) Q4
ORDER BY [PLANGROUP], [YEAR], [MONTH2], [MONTH]
```

Comment: Just dump the output from your query into a temp table and then join to that. So change the first line of your query to `SELECT * INTO #T`     Then, where my answer reads `LEFT JOIN myTable t on` change it to `LEFT JOIN #t t on` YOu might have to change the `JOIN` to join on Month2 as well if this is the month's number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to handle these kind of things is create a date table. How detailed that is, is down to your requirements. In your case you may only need months and years, although if you data is more detailed you may need all dates. You can then use this table and left join your main data to it.

The other option is to build a temp table in your dataset with your months and years in it.

I didn't quite understand what parameters you are passing so I'll just have a guess, hopefully this will give you enough to go on anyway. This assumes you are only ever working with data from no more than 2 years, if not then you are probably better to go down the permanent date table route...

So, if you pass in 4 parameters to your dataset query as 2015; 11; 2016; 10 (Nov'15 to Oct'16)

The your dataset query would look something like.

```
/* uncomment for testing on SSMS only
DECLARE @Year1 int = 2015
DECLARE @Year2 int = 2016
DECLARE @Month1 int = 11
DECLARE @Month2 int = 10
*/

/*Create temp Dates Table*/
DECLARE @d TABLE([Year] int, [Month] int)
INSERT INTO @d 
SELECT @Year1, 1 UNION
SELECT @Year1, 2 UNION
SELECT @Year1, 3 UNION
SELECT @Year1, 4 UNION
SELECT @Year1, 5 UNION
SELECT @Year1, 6 UNION
SELECT @Year1, 7 UNION
SELECT @Year1, 8 UNION
SELECT @Year1, 9 UNION
SELECT @Year1, 10 UNION
SELECT @Year1, 11 UNION
SELECT @Year1, 12 UNION
SELECT @Year2, 1 UNION
SELECT @Year2, 2 UNION
SELECT @Year2, 3 UNION
SELECT @Year2, 4 UNION
SELECT @Year2, 5 UNION
SELECT @Year2, 6 UNION
SELECT @Year2, 7 UNION
SELECT @Year2, 8 UNION
SELECT @Year2, 9 UNION
SELECT @Year2, 10 UNION
SELECT @Year2, 11 UNION
SELECT @Year2, 12


SELECT d.[Year], d.[Month], t.myColumns
    FROM @d d
       LEFT JOIN myTable t on d.[Year] = t.[Year] and d.[Month] = t.[Month]
    WHERE 
       ((t.[Year] *100) + t.[Month]) between (@Year1 *100 + @Month1) and (@Year2 *100 + @Month2) 
    ORDER by d.[Year], d.[Month]
```

Comment: See the comment below please.

Comment: Thank you for the help. This was very useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is the query than I use:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT
      [QUARTER]
      ,[CARRIER]
      ,[PLANGROUP]
      ,[UniqueUsers]
      ,[YEAR]
      ,A.[MONTH]
      ,A.[MONTH2]
FROM [ReportUnit].[dbo].[Month_List] A

LEFT JOIN

(SELECT
        [YEAR]
        ,[MONTH2]
        ,[CARRIER]
        ,[PLANGROUP]
        ,[QUARTER]
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT [CONTRACT_NUM]) AS [UniqueUsers]
FROM
(
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT
        MIN([YEAR]) AS [YEAR]
        ,MIN([MONTH2]) AS [MONTH2]
        ,DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, MIN([MONTH2])-1, CAST('2017-01-01' AS datetime))) AS [MONTH]
        ,[CARRIER]
        ,[PLANGROUP]
        ,MIN([QUARTER]) AS [QUARTER]
        ,[CONTRACT_NUM]
FROM MyTable
WHERE
[YEAR] = @YEAR1
AND [PLANGROUP] IN (@ACCOUNT)
GROUP BY [PLANGROUP],[CARRIER],[CONTRACT_NUM]
) Q1
WHERE
[MONTH] IN (@MONTH1) --THIS IS MONTH NAME PARAMETER IN SSRS
--[MONTH2] IN (11,12)

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT
        MIN([YEAR]) AS [YEAR]
        ,MIN([MONTH2]) AS [MONTH2]
        ,DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, MIN([MONTH2])-1, CAST('2017-01-01' AS datetime))) AS [MONTH]
        ,[CARRIER]
        ,[PLANGROUP]
        ,MIN([QUARTER]) AS [QUARTER]
        ,[CONTRACT_NUM]
FROM MyTable
WHERE
[YEAR] = @YEAR2
AND [PLANGROUP] IN (@ACCOUNT)
GROUP BY [PLANGROUP],[CARRIER],[CONTRACT_NUM]
) Q1
WHERE
[MONTH] IN (@MONTH2)  --THIS IS MONTH NAME PARAMETER IN SSRS
--[MONTH2] IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
) Q1
GROUP BY [YEAR],[MONTH2],[PLANGROUP],[CARRIER],[QUARTER]
) B ON A.MONTH2 = B.MONTH2
) Q4
ORDER BY [PLANGROUP], [YEAR], [MONTH2], [MONTH]
```

And I don`t know how I can join it in your temp Table